# Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression and require.extensions is not supported by webpack. Use a loader instead

Tags: reactjs, cordova, config, webpack-4

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8BY9.jpg)Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.

WARNING in ./node_modules/config/lib/config.js 590:15-36
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in ./node_modules/config/parser.js 38:10-26
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in ./node_modules/config/parser.js 53:9-26
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in ./node_modules/config/parser.js 57:7-25
require.extensions is not supported by webpack. Use a loader instead.

WARNING in ./node_modules/config/parser.js 58:4-19
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in ./node_modules/config/parser.js 68:21-38
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in ./node_modules/config/parser.js 95:15-36
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in ./node_modules/config/parser.js 98:15-34
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in ./node_modules/config/parser.js 108:9-26
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in ./node_modules/config/parser.js 112:9-26
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in ./node_modules/config/parser.js 124:13-33
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in ./node_modules/config/parser.js 128:26-43
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in ./node_modules/config/parser.js 156:14-32
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in ./node_modules/config/parser.js 165:12-30
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in ./node_modules/config/parser.js 173:12-30
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in ./node_modules/config/parser.js 181:11-28
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in ./node_modules/config/parser.js 189:11-28
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in ./node_modules/config/parser.js 202:14-34
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression**strong text**

Comment: How did you resolve this issue?

Comment: Sorry i did not posted how did i resolved.